# For loop error when accessing Dict element: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

I've looked at `'dict' object is not callable` SO answers but don't quite see what I am messing up.

I have an array of dictionaries and then I want to go through each one and access the elements.

```
prebuilt_jars = [
{'name':'xwalk-app-jar', 'binary_jar':'xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar'},
]

for prebuilt_jar in prebuilt_jars:
  prebuilt_jar(
    name = prebuilt_jar['name'],
    binary_jar = prebuilt_jar['binary_jar'],
  )
  jar_deps.append(':' + prebuilt_jar['name'])
```

However I am getting a `'dict' object is not callable` on

`name = prebuilt_jar['name'],`
and

`binary_jar = prebuilt_jar['binary_jar'],`

Do you know what is wrong with my syntax?

**Update**

So what I am doing is trying to condense a whole bunch of rules I have like this:

```
prebuilt_jar(
  name = 'xwalk-app-jar',
  binary_jar = 'xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar',
)

jar_deps.append(':xwalk-app-jar')
```

`prebuilt_jar` is a Buck function that builds a prebuilt jar file.

I want to instead have a dictionary of all my jar objects, and then loop that using those dictionary objects to populate the `prebuilt_jar` call.

**Answer**

I named the loop variable the same as the function name.

```
for pJar in prebuilt_jars:
  prebuilt_jar(
    name = pJar['name'],
    binary_jar = pJar['binary_jar'],
  )
  jar_deps.append(':' + pJar['name'])
```

Comment: No, the error is because you are calling `prebuilt_jar(...)` around those two lines. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I am using Buck (a build script tool for Android). I will post the long hand way of what I am doing.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the `prebuilt_jar(...)` code fragment? What do you want to accomplish in general? Please post the input and the desired output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is, quite literally, a function call syntax on the loop variable:

```
prebuilt_jar(
    name = prebuilt_jar['name'],
    binary_jar = prebuilt_jar['binary_jar'],
  )
```

What is your intent with that code?

I'd imagine that this:

```
for prebuilt_jar in prebuilt_jars:
  jar_deps.append(':' + prebuilt_jar['name'])
```

is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're trying to `call` a dictionary. `prebuilt_jars` is a dictionary, then you do:

```
prebuilt_jar(
    name = prebuilt_jar['name'],
    binary_jar = prebuilt_jar['binary_jar'],
  )
```

As if `prebuilt_jar` is a function. Try doing:

```
for prebuilt_jar in prebuilt_jars:
     print(prebuilt_jar['name'])
     print(prebuilt_jar['binary_jar'])
```

Or something else, if you don't just want to print the items.